# How to make a Qt thread wrapper

Tags: c, multithreading, qt, wrapper

I've written some library code (in C) to facilitate creating and querying threads independent of the platform. Here's a psuedo-code example of the API to create a thread:

```
 result OS_createThread ( 
      pointer to thread handle (set after thread is created), 
      stack size,
      function to run, 
      pointer to parameters,
      priority )
```

Depending on the platform, I use the appropriate c file that contains the particular OS implementation to kick off the thread. E.g.

```
result OS_createThread ( 
 // Windows implementation
 map priority to Windows priority
 // Use Win32 threading call
 CreateThread(blah blah)
```

I've created ports for Win32, POSIX threads, and some RTOSes I've used. Now I need to do this for a Qt environment and I'm a little stumped. First off, I'm a Qt newbie, second it looks like it will require an object oriented approach using the QThread class.

The point of this is to hide the guts of the thread creation to the caller. The caller wants to be able to kick off threads and maintain a handle to that thread so that it can do things in the future like change its priority or kill it.

Using QThreads, does a new QThread object need to be created each time a new thread is requested? Keep in mind that the calling code cannot have anything Qt-specific.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a QThread you would implement a class inheriting from QThread. Example taken from the [QT Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html)

```
class MyThread : public QThread
 {
 public:
     void run();
 };

 void MyThread::run()
 {
     QTcpSocket socket;
     // connect QTcpSocket's signals somewhere meaningful
     ...
     socket.connectToHost(hostName, portNumber);
     exec();
 }
```

And hidden in your implementation would be:

```
result OS_createThread ( 
      pointer to thread handle (set after thread is created), 
      stack size,
      function to run, 
      pointer to parameters,
      priority )
{
  MyThread *thread = new MyThread(size, function, parameters, prio);
  thread->start();
  return thread;
}
```

So your C interface method would create an instance of such a class for each thread being requested. This class should then store all the relevant data passed from your function within its member variables. The thread function to be executed would be called within the `run()` method. Since you seem to execute only C methods I see no problem storing a pointer to them within a class variable (please correct me anyone if I'm wrong - haven't tried it yet ;).

However, its actually a bit more tricky than that, because somebody will have to free the memory created for the `thread` variable. And thats not easily (from a C interface) possible with my example. So you might want to think about using an internal manager class or something that handles the created threads and destroys them as needed. In order to make a qualified statement about how you could achieve this, however, I'd need a bit more information ;)

Comment: Inheriting from QThread is not the best practice for creating threads in Qt after the 4.4 version. Notice that even the Qt documentation is not up to dated. The [qt developers blog](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) has a very good article about the best way to implement threading in Qt.

Comment: good point I wasn't aware of so thanks for the hint. however, the basic principle of the answer should stay the same. so adhere to the new conventions and implement a wrapper accordingly.

Comment: Beautiful. To take care of stopping threads and freeing memory, there is also an API function OS_destroyThread(). It takes a handle to the thread. I simply cast the handle to a pointer of type "MyThread", call terminate(), wait(), and then "delete" the pointer. This kills the thread and cleans up the memory. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If the calling code is not Qt-specific, why do you want to use or implement QThread-s ?

If your goal is to port QThread-s (actually, the QCore library) to your strange operating system, I would first study in detail how they implemented it above Pthreads (assuming you know well the details of posix threads already).

Comment: My code needs to be ported into a Qt application. That part is out of my control. My code is pretty much standard ANSI C and the only things that are platform-dependent are threads, mutexes, etc. So I need to write this wrapper layer. My understanding is that I can't simply create pthreads (this will be running on Linux) within a Qt application.

Comment: QThread are C++ things. You need to learn C++ to use them. And I am not sure you cannot use pthread-s from a code using Qt. I'll try first before porting your glue to QThread-s.